Cold-serve black coffee without acess to ice
In my current work we have fridges and chilled water dispensers, but no freezer or ice maker.  I got into the habit at the last place of making an iced americano in summer by brewing normally in my Aeropress, then adding ice and a little chilled water.  Obviously that's not an option now I don't have ice, and brewing hot then adding chilled water leads to an unpleasantly lukewarm drink.
Aeropress say that you can make a near instantaneous cold brew by stirring for a minute before pressing.  That goes against everything I've read and tried regarding cold brew (though I'll probably give it a go tomorrow anyway).  Otherwise to make cold brew I'd have to steep a day's worth in the fridge overnight, and use the aeropress to strain it - space is tight and we're doing our best to keep the work kitchen worktops uncluttered.  This requires a certain level of forward planning and being in the right place at the right time so isn't ideal.
So I wonder if there's something I'm missing, i.e. with chilled water, a fridge, and an Aeropress how can I make a decent chilled black coffee?

BTW taking ice in isn't going to work, even in an insulated container.  It's 6 hours from when I leave the house until my after-lunch coffee

I would consider a completely different approach: make a small batch of some form of highly concentrated coffee (cold brew comes to mind, but Aeropress would probably work as well), and bring that to work in a small bottle.
When it’s time for your afternoon coffee, use the chilled water from the dispenser to dilute it to the preferred strength.

I'd probably use my moka pot at home in that case - I wonder how well that keeps (or even freezes) or whether I'd have to make it the night before every hot day. With the aeropress I could make it first thing when I get to work, and chill it for a few hours

Cold brew enthusiasts claim that they keep their concentrate for a week. From a more generic food safety perspective, three to four days in the refrigerator should be fine.
